# Xamarin In App Billing Component Not Connecting To Google Play

Tags: xamarin.android, google-play-services, in-app-billing

I have went through the Xamarin IAB 'tutorial' on it's Component page. I installed the component and Google Play Billing Lib into my app, published my apk to Google Play Dev Console in Alpha and added products on the Dev Console to the app. However, when I try to test the app on a phone, anytime I click on any of the purchase buttons nothing happens. The buttons themselves worked fine I have tested them by pushing other notifications, changing colors, etc. They work with everything else, but when it comes to purchasing nothing happens, no pop-ups, no buffering or attempt to connection, literally nothing. I think my app never connects to Google Play, and I have no idea why.

My Main Activity

```
private InAppBillingServiceConnection _serviceConnection;
    private string publicKey = "my public key";

    private IList<Product> _products;

    protected override void OnCreate(Bundle bundle)
    {
        base.OnCreate(bundle);

        // Establish Connection to Google Play Store
        _serviceConnection = new InAppBillingServiceConnection(this, publicKey);

        _serviceConnection.OnConnected += async () =>
        {
            // Load available products and any purchases
            await RequestProducts();
        };

        // Attempt to connect to the service
        _serviceConnection.Connect();

        IAPHelper.Instance.Initalize(_products, _serviceConnection);

        var g = new Game1();
        SetContentView(g.Services.GetService<View>());
        g.Run();
    }

    // Request a list of available products that the user can purchase by providing alist of 
    protected async Task RequestProducts()
    {
        _products = await _serviceConnection.BillingHandler.QueryInventoryAsync(new List<string>{
            ReservedTestProductIDs.Purchased,
            ReservedTestProductIDs.Canceled,
            ReservedTestProductIDs.Refunded,
            ReservedTestProductIDs.Unavailable
        }, ItemType.Product);

        // Were any products returned?
        if (_products == null)
        {
            // No, abort
            return;
        }
    }

    protected override void OnActivityResult(int requestCode, Result resultCode, Intent data)
    {
        base.OnActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
```

My Helper Method

```
private IList<Product> _products;
    private InAppBillingServiceConnection _serviceConnection;

    public void Initalize(IList<Product> _products, InAppBillingServiceConnection _serviceConnection)
    {
        this._products = _products;
        this._serviceConnection = _serviceConnection;
    }

    // Called when a product is clicked to buy
    public bool ProductPurchasing(string id)
    {
        Product _selectedProduct = null;
        try
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < _products.Count; i++)
            {
                if (id == _products[i].ProductId)
                {
                    _selectedProduct = _products[i];
                    break;
                }
            }

            _serviceConnection.BillingHandler.BuyProduct(_selectedProduct);
            return true;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            return false;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Just to pay your attention, `_products` list might not be yet loaded when you pass it to `IAPHelper.Instance.Initalize`. You'd better change `Task RequestProducts()` to `Task<IList<Product>> RequestProducts()` and call `Initalize` immediately after awaiting it.

Comment: That seemed to fix it all thank you!!!